# How to make portlets borderless by default in theme (Liferay)?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

In default (classic) theme portlets are borderless despite the fact it is set "show borders" in their look and feel settings.

In my custom theme based on provided sources, I got bordered portlets by default.

How to set portlets being borderless in my theme too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[liferay-look-and-feel.xml](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/settin-4) can contain some settings, you're looking for this one:

```
 <setting configurable="true" key="portlet-setup-show-borders-default" type="checkbox" value="false"/>
```

Note, with these settings it's even runtime-configurable, providing the default as false.

Comment: This is not working for me on Liferay 7.0 GA3, could something else be overriding it?

Comment: My answer is from 2013, well predating Liferay 7. Seems to be worth a new question

Comment: [Here goes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532143/liferay-7-0-making-all-portlets-borderless-by-default-via-theme)

Comment: [Answer provided in above link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532143/liferay-7-0-making-all-portlets-borderless-by-default-via-theme/41532942#41532942)